# How to delete an object from its pointer?

Tags: java

I have an object that I added to a few different ArrayLists. I wanna avoid changing every list, so I'm trying to change the pointer so all the lists change. But I can't get that to work if I want to set the object to null. For example:

```
ArrayList<Point> list1 = new ArrayList<Point>();
ArrayList<Point> list2 = new ArrayList<Point>();
Point a = new Point(2, 3);
list1.add(a); list2.add(a);
```

At this point, both lists have an item pointing at the same object. With the value "2, 3". If I change the value of the object. Then both lists changes:

```
a.set(5,5);
```

Now both lists have an item of value "5, 5". But if I try to set the value to null.

```
a = null;
```

Now the `a` is set to null, but the object both lists is still "5, 5" and not null like I wanted. I even tried to add a method to the `Point` class to set itself to null. But I couldn't get that to work either. What could I do to delete the object on all lists by changing only the pointer?

Comment: Technically, in Java it's not a "pointer" but rather a "reference".  But either way, changing a pointer/reference doesn't change the object, any more than changing your telephone number would change the color of your hair.

Comment: I think that part of the problem is that there is no such thing as deleting an object in Java. You just have to wait for it to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could I do to delete the object on all lists by changing only the pointer?

Nothing.  There's no way you can do that.  If you want to null the references to the object in the lists (or remove them from the lists) you **must** perform an operation on each of the lists.

If you cannot modify the lists, then consider the following alternatives:

1. Use a different `Point` class that has an extra field that says if the point is "valid" and have the code that is looking at the lists check this field.
2. Create a custom class that represents a nullable reference to a Point; e.g.

   ```
     public class PointRef {
         private Point p;
         public PointRef(Point p) { this.p = p; }
         public Point get() { return p; }
         public void invalidate() { p = null; }
     }

     ArrayList<PointRef> list1 = new ArrayList<PointRef>();
     ArrayList<PointRef> list2 = new ArrayList<PointRef>();
     PointRef a = new PointRef(new Point(2, 3));
     list1.add(a); list2.add(a);

     ...

     a.invalidate;
     // Now both lists contain hold a PointRef that points to a null Point.
   ```

But both of these make *using* the lists and their contained Point objects more complicated.

(@Jeffrey's answer suggests using the `WeakReference` class, but that has the wrong semantics.  In particular, the reference will "break" if the GC detects that there are no strong references to the object.  That's NOT what your use-case requires ... if I understand your question correctly.)

---

Incidentally, I can't think of ANY programming language that would allow you to do what you are trying to do in the way that you propose.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the state of an object held by a reference variable and this will be reflected in all variables that refer to the same object, but if you change the assignment of a reference variable, it effects only that variable. The object referred to is unchanged -- as would be expected.

Comment: So there's no other alternative other than setting the element of every list to null individually?

Comment: Yes. Unless you have one List object and have a bunch of List variables refer to that same List object.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you expand on that?

Comment: It's an extension of what we've already been talking about. A List variable is a reference variable, and you can have multiple reference variables referring to the same List object. If you delete an object from the List, you change its state which will be reflected in all the reference variables that refer to this one same List object. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can't *delete* objects from its "pointers" ("references" to be more precise). When an object has been dereferenced (meaning: there are no references pointing to it) it becomes a candidate for being garbage collected; Java's garbage collector will automatically take care of deleting objects for you, there's no `free()` operation like in other languages (C/C++ come to mind) where you have to manually manage memory.

About your question: you could remove the object from both lists using the `remove()` method in `ArrayList`, or manually setting the object to `null` in the lists given an index (`list.set(index, null)`), but there's no way to delete an object by setting its external references (those outside of the list) to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 'no'. You cannot change contents of an object by changing a pointer to it.

a = null; just clears the pointer, not the object.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there is no simple way to do what you're asking. What you could do, and I don't recommend this, is use [`WeakReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)s in your `List`s. A weak reference will not prevent your `Point` from being garbage collected.

```
List<WeakReference<Point>> list = new ArrayList<>();
Point p = new Point();
list.add(new WeakReference<>(p));
System.out.println(p);
System.out.println(list.get(0).get());

p = null;

System.gc(); System.gc(); System.gc(); System.gc(); // hopefully the GC collects p by now

System.out.println(list.get(0).get()); // null!
```

It would be much, much easier just to manually `remove` the `Point` from both of your `List`s.